# How to restrict the users that can run jenkinsfile tests in pull requests?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have deployed the pipeline-as-code [docker demo with multibranch](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkinsci/pipeline-as-code-github-demo/).

It works alright. I added my github username as the organization and when I make a pull request, the tests are run.

However, when some other user makes a pull request, their tests are also run. I would like to manually approve which pull requests from external contributors are good to run in my jenkins server. Is there a way to do that?

I can do it with [ghprb](https://github.com/janinko/ghprb), but it is not compatible with pipelines, and I want to migrate my jobs to pipelines.

Comment: I believe this use case should be solved by https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Branch+Source+Plugin now.

Answer (score -2):

please try adding these lines in your pipeline script:

```
node('slaveName') {

    properties([
            parameters([
                    string(
                            defaultValue: 'whitelisted1@gmail.com,whitelisted2@gmail.com',
                            description: 'comma separated whitelisted emails',
                            name: 'WHITELIST'
                    )
            ])
    ])

    def authorEmail

        stage('Git') {
            authorEmail = sh([
                    // git log format docs here: https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats
                    script      : "git log -1 --format='%aE'",
                    returnStdout: true
            ]).trim()

            boolean allowRun = isWhitelisted(env.WHITELIST, authorEmail)

            if (allowRun) {
                echo "email ${authorEmail} is whitelisted, proceed execution"
            } else {

                echo "email ${authorEmail} is not in whitelist ${env.WHITELIST}, proceed jenkins job?"
                input message: 'Proceed?'
                // or just abort build with non-zero shell exit
                // currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                // sh "exit 10"
            }

        }
    }
}

@NonCPS
boolean isWhitelisted(whitelist, email) {
    def res = whitelist.tokenize(" ,;").find { white -> white == email }
    return null != res
}
```

Comment: This is not secure. You can easily use any email you want when making a commit, not to mention that they could just change the Jenkinsfile entirely in their branch to bypass this check.

Comment: Perhaps you are right. But does it really make any sense: restrict changing Jenkinsfile for people who are allowed to change your code?

Comment: This question is about pull requests on GitHub. The pull request author isn't necessarily allowed to change your code.